# Ansible - Looping through a list to specify many arguments to a single command

Tags: ansible

I'm would like to use Ansible to create a cronjob that will report disk usage statistics. This requires multiple `--disk-path` arguments. I need to pass in a list, iterate through, and create something along the lines of

`/usr/bin/disk-monitor-script --disk-path={{ item 1 }} --disk-path={{ item 2 }} # etc..`

Given a variable length list along the lines of `[item1, item2, etc..]`

It would be trivial to execute the command many times to create many cronjobs using `with_items`, though I would like to avoid it.

To surmise, how can I build a list of arguments to pass to the script (given a list) in a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Jinja2 [filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html) to join list into string:

```
- command: /usr/bin/disk-monitor-script --disk-path={{ my_items | join(' --disk-path=') }}
  vars:
    my_items: [ item1, item2, item3 ]
```